# Dynamic font-face from custom png base64

Tags: dom, dynamic, base64, styles, font-face

I have a PNG file with some letters that I created myself and I would want to use them in an Angular application to display some writing on the screen. I want to load the font dynamically since I my application creates it. I've come up with the following solution, but it won't work, not even throwing an error:

```
const nodeStyle = document.createElement('style');
    nodeStyle.textContent = `
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'dynamic-font';
      src: url(${pngBase64}) format(png);
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }`;
    document.head.appendChild(nodeStyle);
    
    const nodeParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    nodeParagraph.style['font-family'] = "dynamic-font";
    nodeParagraph.innerHTML = this.inputText;
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(nodeParagraph);
```

I am wondering how would font-face would recognize a bitmap font without some descriptor file, but haven't seen any example yet.

Is this even supposed to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, Angular can be integrated with PixiJS(latest version), which loads custom bitmap fonts as follows:

```
PIXI.BitmapFont.install(fontFile, fontPng);
    PIXI.BitmapFont.from("testFont", {
      fontFamily: "testFont",
      fontSize: 70
    });
    const title = new PIXI.BitmapText("This is the title", { fontName: "testFont" });
```

where fontFile has to be created as an XMLDocument and fontPng is an object of type PIXI.Texture.